# How can I pare down a PDB file in Python to only include specific residues?

Tags: structural-biology, bioinformatics, ccp4, pdb

I'm trying to make a script that will take a MTZ file (reflections), convert it into a CCP4 map, then pare that map down to only encompass a desired area to cut down on the size of my PyMol session files so they're email-able (a.k.a. not 200 MB) and ease the burden on my POS computer.

I currently have a Python script that can `fft` (CCP4) to create the map and `mapmask` to fix unit cell tiling issues.  What I want to add now is something that can take a PDB file and strip out most of it except, for example, residues within 10 Å of #123.

I've been looking at [ProDy](http://www.csb.pitt.edu/ProDy/index.html), but not quite sure where to start.  I would also be open to using something in the CCP4 toolkit.

Comment: I'm curious in the PDB format as well. If you already have a PDB file output, you could try removing all information other than the ATOM lines, and further, remove all the ATOM lines that list atoms from residues outside the range of a subset of your structure. If you could view it in PyMol then perhaps that's good enough?

Comment: @leonardo some sort of manual hack like that may work (as `mapmask` seems to expand a little anyway), but doesn't seem that optimal.  I'll beat on this for a while and let you know what I come up with.

Comment: Is it possible to use a PDB viewing program to select a subregion of a single chain and save a new PDB? If so, you might want to compare the source file to the subregion file and see if it is indeed this simple and then hack yourself a solution.

Comment: Pymol has a selection operator that matches everthing in a specific distance around an atom, is should be possible to use that for this purpose.

Comment: @MadScientist from within a script running outside of PyMol?

Comment: I was thinking manually inside the program, but if you have to automate it, I believe you can use the pymol library from any python script.

Comment: Better fit for scicomp.se?

Comment: @David unfamiliar with that site, if you think it's better there, feel free to flag a mod down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ProDy](http://www.csb.pitt.edu/ProDy/index.html) works quite well, especially from within an existing Python script.

The following code takes an existing PDB file, performs some [selection query](http://www.csb.pitt.edu/prody/reference/atomic/selection.html#selection-operations) on it, then saves it to another file.

```
import prody

def pdbsubset(inpdb, outpdb, selection):
    with open(inpdb) as protf:
        prot = prody.parsePDBStream(protf)
    atoms = prot.select(selection)
    prody.writePDB(outpdb, atoms)
```

An example selection query builder

- `residues` is a list e.g. ['A12', 'A39'] with each element in the form `<chain><residue number>`.  They were captured from the command line using `argparse` with

  ```
      parser.add_argument('-i', '--residues', nargs='+')
  ```

  - so you would specify `-i A12 A39` or whatever.
- `pdb` and `outpdb` are file paths
- `radius` is the distance in angstroms to expand the selection by.

```
reslist = ["(chid {0} and resid {1})".format(res[0], res[1:]) for res in residues]
selector = 'within {0} of ({1})'.format(radius, ' or '.join(reslist))

# and running it:
pdbsubset(pdb, outpdb, selector)
```

The documentation on ProDy selection queries is not the most straightforward, but fairly analogous to PyMol, so doable.

Answer (score 7):

With the program RasMol, you can select, as Mad Scientist explained it for PyMol, everything in a specific distance around an atom. RasMol can be run from command line, using a script (with the -script option under UNIX).